# Highlight range when press another cell

Tags: cells, highlighting, range

If countif example "done" range example from A1:A10 and result appear in cell B1
If result =4 .
I want when click B1 .. the cells in range that contain "done" highlight and color

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1784573/edit) and include more details of what you have (you didn't even mention which program this is in) and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.